# Heroku PHP index.html loads but not style.css or javascript

Tags: php, html, css, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have a simple site where users can write messages & it saves them to the server, or they can read any other message people have wrote on the server too. I wrote the server side in PHP and everything works great on my localhost. I only have 2 PHP files and they get called either on a form submit or via an ajax request. I deployed my site to Heroku, but the only thing that works/displays right now is my index.html. Inside index.html I do not even deal with Javascript or the PHP files, it's simply that the CSS isn't showing. I have Procfile and composer.json at the root of the project, and everything else in /website/.

My composer.json is empty(it's just *{ }* )

My Procfile is

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 /website
```

And my index.html head css reference looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="/website/style.css">
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Yes it's live. https://mysterynote.herokuapp.com/

Comment: The site doesn't have a /website/ directory, but it does have a file style.css in the root.

Comment: The slash wasn't it. I inspected on Chrome and style.css gives a 404 not found error. Do I need to somehow include it elsewhere/a different way? I tried adding index.php & renaming index.html to home.html and include_once(home.html) and it displays the same thing along with comments in the index.php file\

Comment: Ahh a simple directory mistake, that was it! Thank you SO MUCH!!